# Error on starting a new Project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, error-handling, nullpointerexception, compiler-errors

I'm New to android studio.

I was using android studio 2.2.1 and it was working perfectly. But now when I updated it on version 2.2.2 until then I can not create a new project on it.

When i create a new project it prompts me to fill all the required fields i.e Application name, Activity etc but after I click finish it shows the following error.

[image]

Comment: try invalidatecaches/restart if even after restarting issue persist then you have to update your android support plugin ..from sdk manager then also check build.gradle to know which sdk you are using??

Comment: I'm using SDK version 24.

Can you please tell me how to invalidatecaches/restart .?

Comment: Go to file menu there is an option there..

Comment: I did that but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Android support repository is already updated in SDk manager

Comment: Thank You Sir. Just deleted the .AndroidStudio folder and it did the trick for me. You saved my day. Post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem arises with the update sometimes it happens..that settings change for android studio so just Close your android Studio then delete.AndroidStudio setting folder ( in **windows, C:\Users{YOUR_ACCOUNT**}.AndroidStudio )and start your android studio again. It will reconfigure the settings and solves your problem.